Image ratio and filling keep changing instead of remaining the same
I am building an app with a feed. I was able to have the feed working but each item in the feed is not rendering correctly.
depending on the image, the item is more/less changing as shown below:
Image 1:

Image 2:

I am looking to get the feed always looking like the image 1 whatever the image size, orientation, ration. it could be just a center/fit image for example.
Below is the code:
struct FeedPostView: View {
    let post: Post
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(post.images[0])
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 450)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
        .overlay(PostHeaderView(post: post), alignment: .top)
        .overlay(PostCaptionView(post: post), alignment: .bottom)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
        .padding(.bottom, 15)

    }
}

Any idea how to do it ?
Thanks

Why are you using a ZStack here when you're using .overlay?

First of all, .scaledToFill() overrides your .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) because they change the same property. Use either .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit) or .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).
To make your ZStack fill the same space every time, use fixed width and height instead of using maxWidth and maxHeight. You can achieve this using GeometryReader, which will allow you to fill up the same space on every device. If I get you wrong or need more information on this, please comment.
     GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack {
                    Image(post.images[0])
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                }.frame(width: geometry.size.width - 30, height: geometry.size.height * 0.6)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15.0))
                
            }



          

